# Initializing Consumer Module with Play! Framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, rabbitmq, guice

I have a Play Application with a ConsumerService that I want to start and have it listen to a particular RabbitMQ queue on startup. In Play! 2.5, my understanding is that this is now done via a Guide Module so I have a Module.java class in my app's root directly that looks like this:

```
public class Module extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(ConsumerService.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }
}
```

Here is my ConsumerService class:

```
@Singleton
public class ConsumerService {

  private static final String TASK_QUEUE_NAME = "queue";
  private final JPAApi jpaApi;

  @Inject
  public ConsumerService(JPAApi api) throws Exception {
    this.jpaApi = api;
    pullMessages();

  }

  @Transactional
  public void pullMessages() throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    Logger.info(" [*] Waiting for messagez. To exit press CTRL+C");

    channel.basicQos(1);

    final Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

      @Override
      public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        try {
          JPA.em();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("JPA.em() failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
          jpaApi.em();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("jpaApi.em() failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }

      }
    };
    channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);
  }
}
```

Clearly binding this service as an Eager Singleton has its downsides as attempting to get an entityManager via either of these methods throws an exception. My understanding is that it's due to the fact that this class is binded/loaded before Play has initialized the EntityManager factory. Basically the application hasn't started.

Forgive me but even though I've worked with JPA for years, I find this very confusing and not sure what my best approach should be in working around the basic issue: Start up a "Listener" that ultimately needs to do some DB action when it consumes a message.

I'm curious if there's a way I can put the "handleDelivery" method in a transaction, or redesign my initialization flow such that I can call/inject the jpaApi cleanly.

Also, is there any way to start up this consumer in Play 2.5 than the way I'm doing here? I'm having trouble finding such.

I've looked into the [JPAApi.withTransaction](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA#running-transactions-decoupled-from-requests) documentation, but I'm hoping there's a better way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I'm having the same issue- using JPAAPi.withTransaction, em was loaded but connection is still null.

Comment: I have had to wrap every DB call that is not directly related to a controller defined route/action within a jpaApi.withTransaction block